# how to Read Full Text RSS Feed

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, full-text-search, feed

Some sites can get full text Rss feed when the rss address don't have full text
like this site [This](http://fulltextrssfeed.com/)

how can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to screen scrape if a site does not offer an RSS feed?

Comment: nope, i asking how toget all description in rss when rss just have summary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about C#, but I can still give a general answer on how to solve your problem. RSS feeds (almost) always link to the article, hosted on the newspaper/blog's website, where the whole article is available. So the "RSS filler" takes the content of the article from the website content and basically puts it back in the feed, replacing the available (short) intro.

To achieve this you need to:

- parse/generate RSS/Atoms feeds (I'm sure there are plenty of C# libs to do that)
- find the actual article from the html page linked in the original RSS feed. Indeed the linked page contains a lot of things you don't want to put in the "full" RSS feed (such as the website header, nav bar, ads, comments, facebook like button and so on). The easiest way to do this is to use `readability` (a quick google check gives [this lib](https://github.com/marek-stoj/NReadability)).

If you combine both of these, you can achieve your goal.

You can find one implementation of this kind of tool at http://fivefilters.org, and their source code (for older versions) is at /content-only/ http://code.fivefilters.org/full-text-rss/. It's in PHP, but it can give a rough idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the complete script which enlarge the partial rss feed from [Full post rss feed](http://fullpostrssfeed.com) website 
The steps involves:
 - Get the post URL from the RSS feed.
 - Fetch the full content of the post URL, it will use curl to get the content.
 - Parse the content, it uses templates for that. They keep on update the templates for the most popular websites and wordpress themes.  Based on the template,  parse the html content in to html dom objects and then find the content based on the html dom objects.
- Finally, generate the rss feed again with full content.

You can check the script which is written in PHP to get some idea, later you can rewrite the logic to any language.